# How do I plot 2 volume plots on the same figure in plotly?

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

I can't seem to find any answers on how to construct 2 volumes on 1 plotly chart. I have this so far

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Volume(
    x=X,
    y=Y,
    z=Z,
    value=d,
    opacity=0.15,
    isomax = 0.9,
    isomin = 0.3,
    surface_count=17,
    colorbar=dict(title='KDE Norm Value'),
))
```

```
fig.add_trace(go.Volume(dict(
    x=np.linspace(H*(1+tol_up),H*(1-tol_low),100),
    y=np.linspace(C*(1+tol_up),C*(1-tol_low),100),
    z=np.linspace(LO*(1+tol_up),LO*(1-tol_low),100),
    opacity=1, 
 )))
```

Where H, C, tol_up, tol_low, and LO are constants. What's weird is that if I make a 3D scatter using go.Scatter3D, it works and adds a small line. But I want to create a bubble or oblong bubble within my plot, and I can't seem to get it to show up.